# Dismiss multiple ModalViewControllers iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Ok I know there are lots of info on this subject however everything I have tried does not work. My setup is this.

App loads View A which is a Tableview with a navigationController. After a delay I present a ModalView B. On view B i have a button that presents another modalView View C above View B. In Modal View C I have a button to Dismiss C. Now when I hit this button I would also like to dissmis Modal View B taking me back to my RootView which is the mentioned tableView view A.

From Modal View C I have a button but can only dismiss C using the below Action this takes me to modal view B: What I would like to do is remove C and B with this button returning me to A if this is possible?

```
-(IBAction)dismissWebView:(id)sender{

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

I have tried all of these from the above action

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[adsRootView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.adsRootView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

None of which do anything apart from dismissing only Modal view C.

Comment: Question for you: Is there any time in which View C is presented that you DONT want View B to be dismissed at the same time as C?

Comment: @DanF As soon as view C is shown B can be discarded...

Comment: Then why not dismiss B with/without animation when you present C?

Comment: you mean in view B the action to present C dismiss B at same time like this [self presentModalViewController:viewControllerC animated:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];//Dismiss B?

Comment: Just tried it and it doesnt do anything B is never removed?

Comment: I'd be inclined to use a navigation controller (you can hide the navigation bar with [`setNavigationBarHidden:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW9)). Then you can use `popToRootViewController`. Alternatively, if iOS 6, only, you can use unwind segues, which bring this easy "dismiss many controllers" logic to your app.

Comment: You need to call dismiss on B before you present C, otherwise you dismiss C immediately after presentingint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the easy way is to get to your A controller, which is not parent-child relationship in this case, but a presenting/presented relationship:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismiss...]
 ^C   ^B                       ^A
```

But, this is not very clean and will get you when you change your controller hierarchy, so I would advice setting a delegate to notify when it's ok to dismiss controllers.

Comment: Great this worked my hierarchy is not going to change so this is perfect thank you so much!!

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the detailed explanation too makes sense now I see it

Answer (score 2):

I think it is bad practice for a view controller to effectively dismiss itself by making calls on `self.presentingViewController`. I have always used a delegate protocol to allow a presented view controller to inform the presenting view controller if a Cancel or Done button was tapped (or to ask for other information).

To explain this in terms of your example, C would define a protocol that allows it to inform B when the button has been tapped:

```
@protocol CViewControllerDelegate
- (void)cViewControllerDidSelectDone:(CViewController *)viewController;
@end
```

C has a `delegate` property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <CViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

The B view controller has a similar delegate and protocol (although the method name might be different since there is no Done button).

A adopts the BViewControllerDelegate protocol and when it presents B it sets itself as the delegate. Similarly, B adopts the CViewControllerDelegate protocol and when it presents C it sets itself as the delegate.

The button handler in C simply calls the delegate:

```
[self.delegate cViewControllerDidSelectDone:self];
```

The handler for that method in B dismisses the C view controller and informs its delegate (A):

```
- (void)cViewControllerDidSelectDone:(CViewController *)viewController
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.delegate bViewControllerDidSelectDone:self]
}
```

And A's handler for the B delegate method just dismisses B:

```
- (void)bViewControllerDidSelectDone:(BViewController *)viewController
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This style of coding helps separate the different view controllers and ensures that the same class is responsible for presenting and dismissing another view controller.

One final point, `presentModalViewController` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` were deprecated in iOS 6.0. So long as you do not need to support versions before iOS 5.0 it is better to use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for Swift code :

```
self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```